# Filter events based on user input

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

This is the design i have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmP24.png

On the get request i get the data from MongoDB database and render the view. Now i want to filter the data based on the user input on the form.

What would be the best approach to do this?

This is the ejs template:

```
 <div class="row">
            <% events.forEach((event) => { %>
          <div class="col-lg-6 g-mb-30">
            <!-- Event Listing -->                
            <span class="badge  g-font-size-13"><%-event.type%></span>                
            <article class="u-shadow-v39">                  
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="media-body g-pt-40 col-4 text-center g-bg-main">
                        <span class="g-color-orange g-font-weight-500 g-font-size-40 g-line-height-0_7"><%-event.date.getMonth()%></span>
                        <span class="g-line-height-0_7 g-color-white"><%-monthNames[event.date.getMonth()]%></span>
                        <span class="g-color-orange g-ml-5 g-font-weight-500 g-font-size-40 g-line-height-0_7"><%-event.date.getFullYear()%></span>                            
                    </div>                      

                <div class=" col-8 g-mb-5 g-mt-10 ">                                                  
                      <% event.topics.forEach((topic) => { %>
                        <%if(event.topics.length==1){%>
                          <h3 class="  text-center g-pt-35 g-mb-0 u-link-v5 g-color-orange g-color-primary--hover g-font-size-18 g-pr-10">
                          <% }else{%>
                            <h3 class="  text-center   g-mb-0 u-link-v5 g-color-orange g-color-primary--hover g-font-size-18 g-pr-10">
                            <% }%>
                    <%-topic.topic%> </h3>
                    <div class="  text-center u-link-v5 g-color-main g-color-primary--hover g-font-size-18 g-mb-5"><i class="icon-education-097 g-pr-5"></i> <%-topic.time%></div>  
                    <% })%>
                    <h3 class=" text-left g-pb-10 g-mb-0 u-link-v5 g-color-purple g-color-primary--hover g-font-size-18 g-pr-10"><i class="icon-travel-078 g-pr-5"></i> <%-event.location%></h3>

                </div>   


              </div>
            </article>               
          </div>
          <% }) %> 
        </div>
```

This is the get request

```html
//events
function getEvents(req,res,next){
    mongo.find('events','',function(err,res){
        if(!err){
            req.events=res;            
            return next();
        }
    })
}

function renderEvents(req,res){
    res.render('layouts/events',{events:req.events,
        monthNames : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]});
}
app.get('/events',getEvents,renderEvents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you really only have 2 options: do it on the client-side OR do it on the server-side -- which you can do by extending your existing route.

**Option #1: Client-side**

You would attach an `onclick` event handler to your search button. Upon clicking button, you would filter the DOM events by showing or hiding the elements that match the form's criteria. To determine whether the events match the criteria, you would have to extract the information from the DOM. When you are building the HTML for the events, it might be a good idea to add meaningful classes to make it easier to extract information.

Below is a simplified example.

```js
// not sure if you are using jQuery, but we'll use vanilla JS
// though the former makes it easier to do things
window.onload = function() {

  // get references to all elements we'll be using
  var searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form'),
    typeSelect = searchForm.elements['type'],
    monthSelect = searchForm.elements['month'],
    yearSelect = searchForm.elements['year'],
    searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn'),
    eventList = document.getElementsByClassName('event');

  // create an onclick handler for your search button
  searchBtn.onclick = function() {

    // get form values
    var searchType = typeSelect.value,
      searchMonth = monthSelect.value,
      searchYear = yearSelect.value;

    // filter events based on form values
    for (var i = 0, len = eventList.length; i < len; i++) {
      var event = eventList[i];
      // extract values from event thanks to the class names
      var eventType = event.getElementsByClassName('type')[0].innerText,
        eventDate = event.getElementsByClassName('date')[0].innerText;
      var match =
        (!searchType || searchType === eventType) &&
        (!searchMonth || eventDate.indexOf(searchMonth) > -1) &&
        (!searchYear || eventDate.indexOf(searchYear) > -1);

      // show event if it matches criteria
      event.style.display = match ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.event,.row{overflow:hidden}label{display:block}form{overflow:hidden;width:300px}.row{padding:5px 0;}.row .col{float:left;width:45%;padding:5px;}.event{margin-bottom:10px}.event .date{background:navy;clear:left;color:orange;height:150px;float:left;line-height:150px;text-align:center;width:150px}.event .content{float:left;padding-left:5px}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Events Type</label>
      <select name="type">
        <!-- leave first option blank -->
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option>Conference</option>
        <option>Field Trip</option>
        <option>ET Lab</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label>Month</label>
      <select name="month">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>October</option>
        <option>December</option>
        <!-- etc -->
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Year</label>
      <select name="year">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option>2018</option>
        <option>2017</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" id="search-btn">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<h4>All Events</h4>

<!-- when you build your events, use meaningful class names as we will need it later -->
<div class="event-list">
  <div class="event">
    <div class="type">Conference</div>
    <div class="date">9 October 2017</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Robots & Bridge</div>
      <div class="time">4:00 PM to 5:00 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="type">Field Trip</div>
    <div class="date">11 December 2017</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Newtown Creek</div>
      <div class="time">10:00 AM to 12:00 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="type">ET Lab</div>
    <div class="date">7 August 2018</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Robots</div>
      <div class="time">4:00 PM to 5:00 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="type">Field Trip</div>
    <div class="date">11 August 2017</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Lab Ribbon Cutting</div>
      <div class="time">4:00 PM to 5:00 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Option #2: Server-side**

Extend your GET `/events` handler to accept additional but optional request parameters for the type, month, year. I won't go in as much detail as previous but you would change your form so that it can submit.

```
<form method="GET" action="path/events">
    <!-- etc -->
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then in your GET `/events` handler

```
function getEvents(req,res,next){
    var query = {};
    if (req.query.type) {
        // do something to the query with type
    }
    if (req.query.month) {
        // do something to the query with month
    }
    if (req.query.year) {
        // do something to the query with year
    }
    // use query in your find() call 
    // i am not too familiar with mongo but there should be a way to build queries -- i hope
    mongo.find( ... ,function(err,res){
        // everything else stays the same
        if(!err){
            req.events=res;            
            return next();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you think it would be wise not to requery database but rather save the data in a cache and then just filter whatever you have ?

Comment: @ArlindBebja I think it depends such as how much data you have, what type of data you will be filtering on, how much work you want to do, what type of database you have, and many other things. With option 1 (or your idea of saving the data in a cache), you would have to write the filtering yourself but won't need to requery the database again. With option 2, it might easier as the filtering is done by Mongo by passing the correct query - but I do know from experience, you might be limited with how much you can do with the query. There's no right answer.